# Strong parameters with Active Admin: no implicit conversion of Symbol into Integer

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activeadmin, strong-parameters

I'm on Rails 4 and using Active Admin. I need to have a different set of parameters permissible for the `create` and `update` methods, so I am approaching this by modifying the [instructions from the Active Admin documentation](https://github.com/activeadmin/activeadmin/blob/master/docs/2-resource-customization.md). Here is what I am trying to do:

My model needs to take the following set of parameters on create:

```
:name, :region, :contact_details, :province_id, :status_id, :start_date
```

But is should not change `:region` on update. So, without overriding the default Active Admin’s update method, I am modifying `permit_params` as follows:

```
  permit_params do
    params = [:name, :contact_details, :province_id, :status_id, :start_date]
    params.push(:region) unless params[:action] == "update"
    params
  end
```

The result is inevitably the following error:

```
TypeError: no implicit conversion of Symbol into Integer
```

which occurs, I believe, when `permit_params` is creating the method `permitted_params`.

What am I doing wrong? What is the solution?

Comment: Show code where you use `permit_params` method

Comment: `permit_params` are used by ActiveAdmin behind the scenes in its default controllers (please see [here](https://github.com/activeadmin/activeadmin/blob/master/docs/2-resource-customization.md)). I have not written any code that uses `permit_params`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A shorter version of Andrey Deineko

```
 permit_params do
    params = [:region, :name, :contact_details, :province_id, :status_id, :start_date]
    params.delete(:region) if action_name == 'update'
    params
  end
```

console output:

```
2.1.5 :021 > params = [:region, :name, :contact_details, :province_id, :status_id, :start_date]
 => [:region, :name, :contact_details, :province_id, :status_id, :start_date] 
2.1.5 :022 > params.delete(:region)
 => :region 
2.1.5 :023 > params
 => [:name, :contact_details, :province_id, :status_id, :start_date]
```

Comment: Short and sweet indeed. Now I have another problem: although your code works and `:region` is listed among unpermitted parameters during an update method, its value still gets updated. But this probably deserves a question of its own.

Comment: try this `params.delete(:region) if params[:action] == "update"`, might be that `action_name` is not available at that point, but params are sent anyway and params[:action] might work.

Comment: `action_name` is available, thanks for that hint. It was just me being stupid: I was filtering out one parameter and testing another :-)

Comment: Actually, `params.delete(:region) if params[:action] == "update"` was producing the same `TypeError: no implicit conversion of Symbol into Integer`, while `params.delete(:region) if action_name == 'update'` worked fine. Mysterious.

Comment: Cool then, something new for me anyway. Might need this at some point. Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

What if you refactor your code as follows:

```
 permit_params do
    regular_params = [:name, :contact_details, :province_id, :status_id, :start_date]
    update_params = regular_params + [:region]
    permitted = params[:action] == "update" ? update_params : regular_params
    permitted
  end
```

Comment: You cannot use `#push` as that'd modify the original as well. Something like `regular_params + [:region]` should work.

Comment: Yes, this works, thank you. I eventually went with rmagnum2002's variation, and now am perplexed by the fact that although I pass the correct set of parameters to the update method, the deleted parameter (:region) still gets updated.

Comment: @Andrey Deineko: Yes, I have. The shortened list of parameters that is passed to the update method is correct, but for some weird reason the unpermitted parameter still gets updated. I'll need to go deeper.

Answer (score 0):

Try this way, maybe your problem is not with permit params

```
  permit_params :name, :contact_details, :province_id, :status_id, :start_date
  # it does not work as you want but maybe can help you find bug
```

Comment: And what about :region ? He said he don't want :region to be permitted on update. In your case they are permitted in both create and update actions